# SQL Server full text search contians

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

Hopefully this question makes sense - I am not that experienced with full-text searches. I have created a table with several columns covered by a full-text catalog. I have a query using a "Contains" clause to search for a string in those columns. Is there a way to not only return the rows found with that search, but also indicate the column in which the string was found? So, the result would show something like , row X, found in column Y of the table.

Comment: Point of clarification, I am not specifying a column name in the query, but rather using an asterisk i.e.  contains(*, 'blahblah')

Answer (score 0):

I think what I may end up doing is creating a multivalue parameter with a list of all the available columns, then letting the user pick which ones he wants to search, and passing that dynamically into a stored procedure to do the Contains search, on just those columns. At least that will let them specify they wanted to search for the term in certain columns instead of others.